# Audit.Net: Process of saving in different dataprovider

Tags: audit.net

Is it possible to establish some mechanism so that in case the insertion of the audit fails in the default dataprovider, oracle for example, another data provider is used, for example in a file?
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

There is not a data provider with automatic fallback capabilities, but you can [implement a custom data provider](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET#data-providers).

Say you want the Sql data provider by default, and another data provider as fallback. Inherit from the SQL data provider (`SqlDataProvider`) and fallback to another `DataProvider` when a `SqlException` is thrown:

```
public class FallbackSqlDataProvider : SqlDataProvider
{
    public AuditDataProvider FallbackProvider { get; set; }

    public override object InsertEvent(AuditEvent auditEvent)
    {
        try
        {
            return base.InsertEvent(auditEvent);
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            return FallbackProvider?.InsertEvent(auditEvent);
        }
    }
    public override async Task<object> InsertEventAsync(AuditEvent auditEvent)
    {
        try
        {
            return await base.InsertEventAsync(auditEvent);
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            return await FallbackProvider?.InsertEventAsync(auditEvent);
        }
    }
    public override void ReplaceEvent(object eventId, AuditEvent auditEvent)
    {
        try
        {
            base.ReplaceEvent(eventId, auditEvent);
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            FallbackProvider?.ReplaceEvent(eventId, auditEvent);
        }
    }
    public override async Task ReplaceEventAsync(object eventId, AuditEvent auditEvent)
    {
        try
        {
            await base.ReplaceEventAsync(eventId, auditEvent);
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            await FallbackProvider?.ReplaceEventAsync(eventId, auditEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can set the fallback data provider on `FallbackProvider` property, for example like this:

```
var dp = new FallbackSqlDataProvider()
{
    ConnectionString = "cnnstring",
    TableName = "table",
    IdColumnName = "id",
    JsonColumnName = "data",

    FallbackProvider = new Log4netDataProvider()
    {
        Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Log4netDataProvider)),
        LogMessageBuilder = (ev, id) => ev.ToJson()
    }
};

Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup()
    .UseCustomProvider(dp);
```

Also check this [related issue](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/issues/139).

Comment: Hi. Thank you very much for the help, it's perfect